# Labview FPGA pid controller

Tags: fpga, labview

I want to design a PID controller in  LabVIEW for target FPGA Device. My FPGA Device is NI Digital Electronic FPGA board SO any hint will be helpful for me thanks.

Comment: Do you have any concrete problems or questions? "I want to design a PID controller": this is very nice, but it is not a question.

Comment: Actually, i don't know how to add analog pins of DE FPGA board for PID controller so if you help me in this. It will be a lot for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is already there for you:

http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371599L-01/lvfpga/fpga_floating_point_pid/

A few examples are available too, shipped with Labview FPGA